# Determining which TeX Live collection a package belongs to

Tags: packages, texlive

When using the TeX Live Manager or browsing CTAN, sometimes I want to know what TeX Live collection a particular package is found in. What is a convenient way to check?

Comment: With  TeX Live collection you mean the TeX Live version or the used binary package name? The CTAN entry shows if the package is in the current (online) TeX Live version and what's the TeX Live package name is (usually identical to the real package name).

Comment: Also, do you mean the TeX Live collection from 'vanilla' TL or say when repackaged for a Linux distribution?

Comment: I am referring to a TeX Live installation installed directly from http://www.tug.org/texlive/. I don't see any collection information listed that Web site or CTAN.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The terminal command

```
tlmgr show abc
```

answers with

```
package:     abc
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Support ABC music notation in LaTeX.
longdesc:    The abc package lets you include lines of music written in the ABC Plus language. The package will then employ the \write18 facility to convert your notation to PostScript (using the established utility abcm2ps) and hence to the format needed for inclusion in your document.
installed:   Yes
revision:    15878
cat-version: .0
cat-date:    2008-03-08 20:47:21 +0100
cat-license: lppl
collection:  collection-music
```

Pardon the advertising. :)

It will show the information also for not installed packages.

Comment: And if there is no `tlmgr` command?  On some systems it cannot even be meaningfully used (e.g. NixOS) and on others it takes an expert to use (e.g. Ubuntu).  I have found this list: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb , is it "official"?  Is there anything better?

Comment: @Alexey There are so many variations! Never heard of NixOS.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand: variations of what?  There is not "official" partition of packages into collections?  It is not documented?

Comment: @Alexey Debian, for instance, uses a packaging that mostly reflects TeX Live “collections”. With `apt` I'm sure you can look at the contents of each package; recent versions of TeX Live/Debian allow using `tlmgr`.

Comment: Ok, but where are TeX Live "collections" documented or listed?

Comment: I have posted a separate [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356831/37291).