# TeX Live package collection organisation

Tags: packages, texlive

This question is closely related to [*Determining which TeX Live collection a package belongs to*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34795/37291), and maybe remotely to [*What font packages are installed in TeX live?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59403/37291).

I am a bit confused about the organisation of TeX Live packages into "official" collections and about contents of some TeX Live packages.  Also, the relation between "packages" that can be used with `\usepackage` and "packages" in the sense of [CTAN](http://ctan.org/) is not very clear to me.  Moreover, I do not know if packages in CTAN correspond bijectively with packages of TeX Live.  (I know however that OS-specific distributions of TeX Live have their own packages.)

1. I know that TeX Live packages are often organised into collections like `collection-latexrecommended`, `collection-latexextra`, `collection-science`.  Does there exist an "official" partition of packages into collections?  Can I brows it somewhere?  I have found some listing here:

   - http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb Is this a reliable source for TeX Live package organisation?  Is there a better one?
2. Where can I see which `\usepackage`-type packages each CTAN package provides, and vice versa, which CTAN package provides a given `\usepackage`-type package?  For example, I am confused about the relation between `lmodern` LaTeX package, which has an a bit obscure entry [in CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/documentation/lmodern) and [`lm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm) CTAN package.  For example, can `lmodern` be available without `lm` being installed?  If yes, would Latin Modern font be installed in this case?  Conversely, can I have a situation where `lm` is installed, but either `lmodern` package or the actual Latin Modern font in unavailable?[^debugging_case]

[^debugging_case]: I am actually debugging a situation where `lm` TeX Live package must have been installed in NixOS user profile, but Latin Modern font was not available in XeLaTeX in `\setmainfont` without installing an OS-specific Latin Modern font package.

Comment: Not a full answer, but `texlive.tlb` is where TeX Live gets the information about packages from: for a local install you can read the version in your tree to see what 'your' TeX Live 'thinks'.

Answer (score 20):

The confusion here arises from a complete overload of the word `package`, which can refer to many different things here. Let us try to distinguish most of these packages a bit more, beginning from the smallest unit.

- **Style file**: `\usepackage{aaa}` This is used in LaTeX source code and references one particular `.sty` file that will be loaded.
- **CTAN package**: These are sets of files developed by the same person or group, sometimes containing only one `.sty` file, sometimes containing many of them and other files (fonts, metrics, data, ...).
- **TeX Live package**: This is what you can install in TeX Live with `tlmgr` that is not called `collection-*` or `scheme-*`. These are usually the same as the CTAN packages, with very few exceptions.
- **TeX Live collections**: These are groups of TeX Live packages / CTAN packages.  The packages are roughly ordered by use and relevance.
- **Distribution packages**: Distributions (like Debian, RedHat, and SuSE) often repackage the TeX Live distribution into their own format and units. Debian creates one Debian package for each collection in TeX Live.  Other distributions do it differently.

You asked what are the *official* places to check.  That is not easy:

- **Style files**: There is no easy way, since there are too many of them, and many are not used directly with `\usepackage`.  The only way is to check the list of files available.  In TeX Live you can do that with `tlmgr search --file .sty`, which will give you a long list of CTAN/TeX Live package names and contained style files (BTW, currently 4509 files).
- **CTAN package**: [CTAN itself](https://ctan.org) has extensive search and browsing options.
- **TeX Live package**: The authoritative source of packages in TeX Live is best found in the list of `tlpsrc` files in the [subversion repository](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/tlpkg/tlpsrc/).  However, this will not help you much, because there are no descriptions or files contained.  You can again use `tlmgr info` which will list all packages, including whether they are installed or not, and the short description.  You also mentioned http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb, which is definitely fine and readable, but `tlmgr` might be more comfortable to query this data.
- **TeX Live collections**: see above, or use `tlmgr info collections`
- **Distribution packages**: every distribution has its own info pages

To go through your example of `lm` versus `lmodern.sty`, you could do the following.

Use `tlmgr` to find which package provides `lmodern.sty`:

```
$ tlmgr search --file lmodern.sty
lm:
      texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
```

Then use `tlmgr info` to get more details:

```
tlmgr info lm
package:     lm
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Latin modern fonts in outline formats
longdesc:    The Latin Modern family of fonts consists of 72 text fonts and 20 mathematics fonts, and is based on the Computer Modern fonts released into public domain by AMS (copyright (c) 1997 AMS). The lm font set contains a lot of additional characters, mainly accented ones, but not exclusively. There is one set of fonts, available both in Adobe Type 1 format (*.pfb) and in OpenType format (*.otf). There are five sets of TeX Font Metric files, corresponding to: Cork encoding (cork-*.tfm); QX encoding (qx- *.tfm); TeX'n'ANSI aka LY1 encoding (texnansi-*.tfm); T5 (Vietnamese) encoding (t5-*.tfm); and Text Companion for EC fonts aka TS1 (ts1-*.tfm).
installed:   Yes
revision:    28119
sizes:       src: 4817k, doc: 2629k, run: 42581k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 2.004
cat-date:    2015-08-03 05:43:12 +0200
cat-license: gfsl
cat-topics:  font font-proportional font-mono font-type1 font-otf font-cm
collection:  collection-fontsrecommended
```

If you want to see all files contained in `lm`, just add `--list` to the above invocation and it will give you all contained files.

Finally, you can also browse the `lm` package by going to https://ctan.org/pkg/lm, where you can confirm that the respective TeX Live package name is `lm` ("Con­tained in    TEX Live as lm").

Answer (score 7):

`tlmgr` tool has most of the information that you need, for example if you query it for `lmodern` then

```
$ tlmgr list  lmodern
tlmgr: package repository http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: cannot find package lmodern, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `lmodern' in their title/description:
fixcmex - Fully scalable version of Computer Modern Math Extension font

Packages containing files matching `lmodern':
lm:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
```

So in texlive `lmodern.sty` is just in the `lm` package. The ctan entry for `lmodern` seems particularly strange being a historical note of discussions rather than relating to any real download. It could probably renamed.

Comment: Thanks for the information about `lmodern`.  Otherwise, I would like to have a simple document of web page to see this information.  I do not even have `tlmgr` on NixOS, for example, and it would be mostly useless there.

Comment: @gernot not necessarily, some linux distributions package texlive without tlmgr so that you use the system package manager apt-get or yum or whatever

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right ...

Comment: @Alexey there are thousands of packages I'm not sure what a simple document with information about all of them could look like. Also if you are using a linux distribution repackaging, then the answer of which latex package is in which package for the system package manager is specific to that distribution, not anything the upstream texlive can document

Comment: For the record, even on Ubuntu `tlmgr` was installed but didn't work (possibly it could be made to work on Ubuntu with [some nontrivial system configuration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/37291)).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, are you saying that there is no any online page which would have the information accessible by `tlmgr`?

Comment: yes, but also it would be of no use to you as you need to use the linux system's package manager query to ask it which of _its_ packages contain lmodern. A web page listing the classification used by tlmgr is of no interest if you don't have tlmgr.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the distribution repackaging could be made to follow the "official" packaging, if such exists.  So, before deciding if anything is to be done about the distribution packaging, i wanted to be sure that `lm` is *really* (supposed to be) in `collection-fontsrecommended`.