# Suddenly `` and -- is not translated to curly quotes and en-dash

Tags: xetex, texlive

I'm using TexLive running Xelatex on Arch from Neovim with Vimtex, all the latest version.

I haven't used LaTeX for a while and after a full system upgrade, I'm noticing some problems with my current LaTeX build. Most of them, like "`latexmk` is not an executable" due to TexLive being restructured are already solved, but I have yet to solve problems like this that I don't know where to start.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Curly ``quotes'' on Austro--Astrophotography---here.
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the MWE result]

The log file

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.6.10)  6 JUL 2023 22:47
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22> (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
Font mapping `tex-text.tec' for font `[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;' not found.
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count189
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count190
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count191
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count192
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3.
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2022/07/10 v2.5l Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 460 strings out of 476683
 9400 string characters out of 5809790
 1842018 words of memory out of 5000000
 20786 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512295 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,5n,38p,143b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

I found in line 13 something is not found. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Works perfectly here. Look at the log file if you have any error/warning

Comment: The log file should be quite short. Please, add it to your question. What's printed if you add `\fontname\font` to your document?

Comment: @egreg thanks, the paste is included now. As for the code, it outputs `"[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt`. Maybe connected to the line 13 in the log file?

Comment: @Andre Please avoid external links. The point of this site is that questions and their answers remain usable in the future. This link is likely to break too soon for that. Post the log here, it's short anyway.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can reproduce on my laptop; this is definitely due to the ArchLinux reorganization of the texlive packages. (I hadn't gotten around to deal with it on the laptop yet.)

Try `pacman -S texlive-xetex`; if that doesn't fix it, try `pacman -S texlive-meta`.

(That the offending missing package is `texlive-xetex` is only an educated guess; certainly my desktop which has the full `texlive-meta` set does not show the same problem.)

Comment: Installing `texlive-xetex` solved the problem. Thank you! I'm curious, what do you think was happening here?

Comment: Previous Arch packaged texlive differently from how upstream packaged it. TeXLive officially curates _collections_ of packages, so you don't have to install packages one at a time but you can install all packages of the same type at once. [See e.g. this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356918/119). On the other hand, Arch used to split all the packages up _in a different way_ into individual Arch Linux packages that you can install via `pacman`. [Very recently the maintainers decided this difference is silly](https://archlinux.org/news/tex-live-package-reorganization/).

Comment: This change is a good thing as, if you don't want a _full_ TeXLive installation, the new packaging scheme makes it easier to find which package you want installed (since you can now use `tlmgr` output). As each package in the "old" scheme has often multiple nontrivial intersections with packages in the "new" scheme, and vice versa, it is not possible to automatically determine which collections a given user actually want (made worse by the fact that there wasn't a meta package to install all/most of texlive originally).