# XeLaTeX doesn't turn two hypens into an endash anymore

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I have been using XeLaTeX (TeX Live on Linux) for several years and two dashes have always been turned into an en-dash. For some time now (maybe since I installed TeX Live 2023) this doesn't happen anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}   % does not work
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}      % does not work
\setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
Two hyphens -- are not automatically replaced by an en-dash \textendash.

Three hyphens --- are not automatically replaced by an em-dash \textemdash.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Everything is fine with LuaLaTeX, but I'd rather use XeLaTeX :)
Any suggestions?

Comment: It's everything working fine for me both in `Xe` and `LuaLaTeX`, can you update your `TeX` distributions

Comment: I believe to have seen a question like yours, which depended on the particular distribution on a particular operating system. What are yours? Look in the log file for `tex-text`: you should see some warning.

Comment: see [Suddenly `` and -- is not translated to curly quotes and en-dash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690449/suddenly-and-is-not-translated-to-curly-quotes-and-en-dash)

Comment: @UdiFogiel Yes, that's the one I seemed to remember.

Comment: @UdiFogiel Installing texlive-xetex (I'm using Manjaro) solved the problem. Thank you!